# Share a folder with google apps script without receiving an email

Tags: google-apps-script

I want ask you if you know a method that can share folder in drive with google apps script, but without receiving an Email for the editors. 
I have tried with the following option into my programm but in vain : "folderName.permission.EDIT"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it by using the advanced Google services.

Please open the apps script editor, navigate to **Resources > Advanced Google services...**

[image: menu]

then scroll all the way down to **Drive API** and toggle the switch to "on"

[image: enable drive api]

Once you've done that, then you can use the following code as a template to share folders without sending notification emails to the users -

```
function myFunction() {
  var folderID = 'PasteTheFolderIDHere';
  Drive.Permissions.insert({
      'role': 'reader', // or writer, fileOrganizer, organizer, owner
      'type': 'user', // or group, domain, anyone
      'value': 'example@domain.com'
    },
    folderID,
    {
      'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' // this is important
    });
}
```

You can test this out on the [Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert) too. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello, Thank you, well done,I have activated  the drive's API. On the other side I don't know if this API is paying. Many thanks

Comment: @OUALITYoucef - glad that it helped! Kindly consider accepting the answer too :) - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer